# Select Item in grid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am using smart gwt2.2 on windows system, with browser Mozilla.
In smart gwt I am using a ListGrid.And in that ListGrid for one field I have set the editor type to Select Item.

SelectItem item = new  SelectItem();
ListGridField field = new ListGridField("Field", "Field");
field.setEditorType(item);

My problem is that is I set the simple string value map to the Select Item then it works fine, But while same list coming from server side and I try to set then it is giving this error,

Uncaught JavaScript exception [this.formItem is undefined] in http://127.0.0.1:8888/nextenders/sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js, line 1831

I am not getting at which place I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the same field name to both SelectItem and ListGridField

```
 SelectItem item = new SelectItem("fieldName");
 ListGridField field = new ListGridField("fieldName", "title");
 field.setEditorType(item);
```

Comment: check if the DataSource "fieldName" also matches with the ListGridField "fieldName"